# gwidgets gtable refresh

Tags: r, gwidgets

I encounter the following problem:

```
library(gWidgets)
options(guiToolkit = "RGtk2")

aa <- c(1,2,3)
bb <- c(4,5,6)
cc <- cbind(aa,bb)
cc <-as.data.frame(cc)

t1 <- gtable(cc, container=TRUE)
```

I want to refresh the content of t1 with:

```
dd <- c(7,8,9)
dd <- as.data.frame(dd)
```

But when I run

```
t1[] <- dd
```

I receive: `Can't replace with fewer columns`

Apostolos

Comment: Puzzled by the comment above. It certainly "looks" like an [r] question

Comment: @meteorainer, it is an R question. `gWidgets` is an R package (http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gWidgets/index.html). I think the user doesn't deserve -1. In fact, he provided a complete reproducible example, which is a thumb up!

Answer (score 3):

To expand upon John's answer, here's an example.

```
#Data
cc <- data.frame(aa = 1:3, bb = 4:6)
dd <- data.frame(X = 7:9)

#Wigdets
win <- gwindow()
grp <- ggroup(container = win)
t1 <- gtable(cc, container = grp)

#Refresh widget
delete(grp, t1)
t1 <- gtable(dd, container = grp)
```

Note that the sample code in the question works fine under `gWidgetstcltk`; it's a purely GTK issue.

Answer (score 2):

The gtk widget makes you pick the type of column at construction, so gtable doesn't let you have fewer columns or change column types. If you really want to do this, put the widget in a ggroup container, then delete and add a new widget.

Comment: Care to give an example? I've never worked with this package and would love to try it.

Answer (score 0):

If it is only about refreshing instead of completely changing its content I made very nice experience with something like this:

```
win <- gtable(data.frame(a=rnorm(100),b=runif(100)),container=T)
win[1,1] <- 5
win[1:10,2] <- 6
win[seq(dim(win)[1]),seq(dim(win)[2])] <- win[seq(dim(win)[1]),seq(dim(win)[2])] +1
```

a complete 'refresh' might look like this:

```
win <- gtable(data.frame(a=rnorm(100),b=runif(100),d=FALSE),container=T)
```