# Is there a way to get the container from a gWidget?

Tags: r, object, user-interface, gwidgets

#### question

I note that `delete(obj,widget,...)` requires the container/parent `obj` of the widget that is to be deleted. Is there an easy way to pull this from `widget` directly?

#### context

I'm trying to write a quick 'foolproof' widget refresh function that deletes and re-adds the same widget (a la https://stackoverflow.com/a/6571570/2023432) or another one to replace it, and ran into the above problem early:

```
refresh.widget <- function(old.widget, new.widget = old.widget) {
    delete(old.widget$container, old.widget)
    new.widget
}
```

Comment: In `gWidgets2` this becomes easy, as containers have a children field, so the children can be accessed by `container$children`. You may have to filter to get the one you want. Heads up: if I recall correctly `delete` for some toolkits really does delete the widget, for others it just removes it from the container.

Comment: Definitely looking forward to migrating to gWidgets2 once I finish this project. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry then, keeping track of children at the `gWidgets` level wasn't added until the rewrite. Not sure how you would work around this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only workaround I can think of is to build a hierarchy for each widget tree with some functions that will take in a list; something like

```
widget.tree <- list()
add.widget <- function(tree,my.parent,new.widget) {
  widget.tree[new.widget] <- list(widget = new.widget, 
                                  parent = my.parent)
  add(my.parent, new.widget)
}
```

and then interacting with widgets in a tree solely through functions that operate on these attributes. This seems kind of like a lot of machinery though, which starts to take you back to working directly with GUI toolkits through R, losing you the ease of `gWidgets`. I'm not going to use this workaround, myself. As @jverzani said, it's far better to use `gWidgets2` if you can.